# Replacing one slide in several open presentations

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I cobbled together some VBA code in the hopes of replacing a single, identical slide in several open presentations.

This pasted the new slide at the end rather than where the old slide was deleted. Also, I'd need this to happen with all open presentations. Note that I identify slides by SlideID.

```
Sub ReplaceOneSlide()
ActivePresentation.Slides.FindBySlideID(1846).Delete
Dim sourcePresentation As Presentation
    On Error Resume Next
    Set sourcePresentation = Application.Presentations("X:\Marketing Presentations (Final) \Slide Library\Slide Library.pptm") 'change the name accordingly
    If sourcePresentation Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Source presentation not found!", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

    Dim vSlideIDs As Variant
    vSlideIDs = Array(1846) 'change the slide IDs accordingly

    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(vSlideIDs) To UBound(vSlideIDs)
        sourcePresentation.Slides.FindBySlideID(vSlideIDs(i)).Copy
        ActivePresentation.Slides.Paste
    Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using an array to hold one value?

```
  Dim vSlideIDs As Variant
    vSlideIDs = Array(1846) 'change the slide IDs accordingly

    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(vSlideIDs) To UBound(vSlideIDs)
        sourcePresentation.Slides.FindBySlideID(vSlideIDs(i)).Copy
        ActivePresentation.Slides.Paste
    Next i
```

Instead try something like this (largely air)code:

```
 Dim lSlideIDs As Long
 Dim oSld as Slide
 Dim lIndex as long

    lSlideIDs = 1846 'change the slide IDs accordingly
        lIndex = sourcePresentation.Slides.FindBySlideID(lSlideIDs).SlideIndex
        sourcePresentation.Slides.FindBySlideID(lSlideIDs).Copy
        ActivePresentation.Slides.Paste
        Set oSld = ActivePresentation.Slides(ActivePresentation.Slides.Count)
        oSld.MoveTo lIndex
    'Next i ' commenting this out, per OP's comment; my bad
```

Comment: Steve. Thank you so much for this guidance. It didn't quite work. I had the source file open. I had four other presentations open. I entered the macro in presentation 1. The macro copied the right slide in the source file, deleted the same SlideID in the target file but pasted the copied version at the end. I need it copied in the same location as the deleted version. Also, it only ran in presentation 1 but not any of the others that were open. I deleted "Next i" at the end because I got a bug window that said "Next i without For". Here is what I ran:

Comment: Sub ReplaceOneSlideInOpenPresentations()

Dim sourcePresentation As Presentation
    On Error Resume Next
    Set sourcePresentation = Application.Presentations("X:\Marketing Presentations (Final) \Slide Library\Slide Library.pptm") 'change the name accordingly
    If sourcePresentation Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Source presentation not found!", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

    Dim lSlideIDs As Long
 Dim oSld As Slide
'more in next box

Comment: lSlideIDs = 1854 'change the slide IDs accordingly
        sourcePresentation.Slides.FindBySlideID(lSlideIDs).Copy
        ActivePresentation.Slides.FindBySlideID(lSlideIDs).Delete
        ActivePresentation.Slides.Paste
        
  

End Sub

Comment: Re Next i, sorry, my mistake. Shouldn't be there. And see edited version for moving the pasted slide to what I think is the position you want.

Comment: OK. Many thanks. Didn't work. Same setup. Four target presentations open + source file open. Ran macro in Presentation 1. It copied right slide, then pasted it at the end, without deleting bad slide, which is closer to the front of the deck. Also got runtime error saying "Slide (unknown member): Integer out of range. 53 is not in the valid range of 1 to 38" . 53 is slide NUMBER in source but I need to use its slideID. Target deck had 38 slides (once new slide was added at end).

Comment: Also, none of the other target presentations changed.

Comment: The code as it stands won't change any but the active presentation (not all open presentations).  Let's get the basics working then mod it to do all open presentations. I'd post whatever code you CURRENTLY have and explain what's not working.