# How to replace a slide by SlideID in open presentation

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I want to grab an updated slide from my library of slides (source file) and use a macro to find the same slide in the open presentation and replace it with the updated slide. But I need to define slides by SlideID, not page number. So the action is: find slide (by SlideID) in open presentation, delete it, insert AT THE VERY SAME LOCATION the updated slide (with SAME SlideID) in the source file.

I tried the code below but it deletes the bad slide in open presentation then pastes the good slide AT THE END instead of IN THE SAME LOCATION. THANKS for any help fixing this.

```
Sub ReplaceOneSlide()
ActivePresentation.Slides.FindBySlideID(1854).Delete
Dim sourcePresentation As Presentation
    On Error Resume Next
    Set sourcePresentation = Application.Presentations("X:\Marketing Presentations (Final) \Slide Library\Slide Library.pptm") 'change the name accordingly
    If sourcePresentation Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Source presentation not found!", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

    Dim vSlideIDs As Variant
    vSlideIDs = Array(1854) 'change the slide IDs accordingly

    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(vSlideIDs) To UBound(vSlideIDs)
        sourcePresentation.Slides.FindBySlideID(vSlideIDs(i)).Copy
        ActivePresentation.Slides.Paste
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: You'll need to get the .SlideIndex of the slide you are deleting.  That will let you insert the new slide into the same position.

Comment: I'll stand corrected, but I believe that when copying a Slide with a specific SlideID from one presentation to another presentation, the original SlideID is not retained, and a new one is allocated. Which means you're going to find another method of matching slides between presentations.

Comment: @TechnoDabbler, that's correct. SlideID is guaranteed to be unique, so when a new slide is created/copied/pasted in/whatever, it gets a new and unique SlideID. This is a repeat of the same question asked elsewhere, btw. Paul, it'd be better to follow up in the original thread rather than starting over here.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57501968/replacing-one-slide-in-several-open-presentations

Comment: Try naming the slides and using that to find, delete and paste the slides.  Although once pasted you would have to name the slide, since PPT will rename automatically when you paste it.

Comment: Gents, Thank you. I crafted a solution using SlideID. If I Cut/Paste a slide using keyboard commands from one presentation to another, the sames SlideID is retained in both. My macro specifies the SlideID in the source file, copies it, goes to the ActivePresentation, finds the same slide, deletes it, then pastes the updated slide from the source file. The key is to delete the slide being replaced, go back one slide so that it is selected, then paste. In this way, you avoid pasting in a slide "that already exists" and takes on a new ID. Here's my code. Not pretty but works.

Comment: Sub SlideReplateTest1(); Dim sourcePresentation As Presentation; On Error Resume Next; Set sourcePresentation = Application.Presentations("X:\Marketing Presentations (Final) \Slide Library\Slide Library.pptm") ; If sourcePresentation Is Nothing Then; MsgBox "Source presentation not found!", vbExclamation;  Exit Sub; End If; On Error GoTo 0; Dim vSlideIDs As Variant; vSlideIDs = Array(1854);    Dim i As Long; Dim I_ID As Integer; I_ID = ActivePresentation.Slides.FindBySlideID(1854).SlideIndex; For i = LBound(vSlideIDs) To UBound(vSlideIDs) [see next comment]

Comment: sourcePresentation.Slides.FindBySlideID(vSlideIDs(i)).Copy
    ActivePresentation.Slides.FindBySlideID(vSlideIDs(i)).Select
    ActiveWindow.View.Slide.Delete
    With ActiveWindow
    With .View
      lCurSlide = .Slide.SlideIndex
      If lCurSlide < ActivePresentation.Slides.Count Then .GotoSlide (lCurSlide - 1) Else .GotoSlide (1)
    End With
    If .ViewType = ppViewNormal Then .Panes(ppViewNotesPage).Activate
  End With
  
    ActiveWindow.View.Paste
            
    
  Next i

End Sub

Comment: I am now trying to figure out how to save and close the active presentation and automatically run the macro in any other open presentation except the source file-- so that I can, for example, open five presentations, run the macro, and replace the relevant slide in each one, saving each presentation as I go.

Comment: >> If I Cut/Paste a slide using keyboard commands from one presentation to another, the sames SlideID is retained in both. <<  Not necessarily.  If the source SlideID doesn't exist in the destination presentation, then yes. If there's already a slide with SlideID=X in the destination presentation, the source slide will get a new SlideID when you paste it in.  So unless you can be utterly certain that your SlideIDs are not duplicated anywhere, it's best not to rely on them not changing.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Steve. I think I'm going to have to rely on the Title/Name of the slide and just make sure they are all unique. Unfortunately, they are not currently but I can fix that. I'll have to figure out how to go to / select a slide by title/name. I'll research that.

Answer (score 1):

Re "how to save and close the active presentation and automatically run the macro in any other open presentation except the source file", off top of head:

```
Dim oPres as Presentation
Dim sMyName as String

sMyName = "BlahBlah" ' fill in the name of the pres with macros here

For Each oPres in ActivePresentations
  If Not Ucase(oPres.Name) = Ucase(sMyName) Then
     ' do whatever's needed to oPres here
     oPres.Save
     oPres.Close
  End if
Next
```

Comment: Hey Steve, thanks for the email reply - I've put it up [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58140807/1188513) as a CW answer crediting you, but feel free to post your own (I'll upvote it)