# Latest Excel for Mac no longer compiles

Tags: excel, vba, macos, compiler-errors

The following code works fine on latest Excel Windows and also on Excel 16.28 on Mac. But on the latest Excel for Mac (16.29 and 16.30) it generates this error: "Compile error:  Method or data member not found" on the code line `MyShape.Select`.

I assume that there is an alternative way to do what I want that the compiler will approve of, but I don't know what it would be. As an alternative, I tried not selecting the shape and just referring to it, but then I get the same error but on the `With MyShape.ShapeRange.Fill` line.

```
  Dim MyShape As Shape
  'Other stuff
  Set MyShape = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 400, 400, DistanceBetweenCells, LineWidth)
  MyShape.Select
  With Selection.ShapeRange.Fill
    'stuff here
  End With
```

I'm hoping that a newer version of Mac Excel, when released, will revert to the older version in allowing the above, but assuming that's not the case, any workarounds?

Comment: Just to clarify - are you getting a **compile** error, or **run-time** error 438? Because `Selection` is `Object`, so any member calls against it are necessarily late-bound, making a compiler error rather unlikely (read: impossible).

Comment: The impossible strikes - it is a compile error!

Comment: I can only tell  you what I see.  Works fine in version 16.28.  In version 16.29 it produces these precise words:  "Microsoft Visual Basic.  Compile Error:  Method or data member not found."  This happens when I do the code as a selection or when I refer to shape or shape range.  When referring to shaperange, for example the word shaperange is the word that is highlighted by the compiler.  "Shape" is highlighted when I use "With MyShape.Shape.Fill" and "Select" is highlighted when I do "MyShape.Select."

Answer (score 1):

I like that you're *explicitly* referring to `ActiveSheet`, kudos!

The problem is that `ActiveSheet` is an `Object`, wich means the compiler is helpless: `ActiveSheet.Shapes` compiles, but so will `ActiveSheet.Shapess` - even with `Option Explicit` specified. The entire expression is evaluated at run-time.

Let's fix that first:

```
Dim sheet As Worksheet
Set sheet = ActiveSheet
```

Now `sheet.Shapes` gets intellisense and compile-time validation, along with subsequent the `.AddShape` member call. You even get parameter tooltips as you type up the argument list!

What happens next is interesting: you declared `MyShape` as a `Shape`, but it's not a `Shape` you're looking at - the `Shape` class doesn't have a `ShapeRange` property, so... where does `MyShape.ShapeRange` come from then?

If you break execution (F9 to set a breakpoint) after the `MyShape.Select` call, and then bring up the *immediate pane* (Ctrl+G), the answer appears:

```
?typename(selection)
Rectangle
```

If you press Shift+F2 on the word `Rectangle`...

```
Dim myRectangle As Excel.Rectangle '<~ here
```

...the VBE doesn't seem to figure it out ("identifier under cursor is not recognized"). So we press F2, then right-click somewhere and tick the "Show hidden members" option - and sure enough, there it is:

[image: Rectangle.ShapeRange in the VBE's Object Browser]

So your code says "let's use the `Shape` interface", but works with a `Rectangle` object. And since that works, it means a `Rectangle` "is a" `Shape`: the two interfaces simply describe the same object through different lens, so either works... but then `Shape.ShapeRange` doesn't look quite right, since the `Shape` class doesn't define that member *and that's the interface we explicitly said we were going to be working with*.

If we want to invoke the members of `Rectangle`, we can - and since we're now showing hidden members in the object browser, intellisense displays the hidden types and members too. If the entire `With` block is early-bound, everything makes much more sense:

```
With myRectangle.ShapeRange.Fill
```

...and explains how the late-bound code off `ActiveSheet` would work at run-time to resolve the member call, and now the compiler needs a completely other strategy to compile the VBA code: *maybe* that could shake things up enough to get it to work, maybe it won't. At least the type ambiguities and ignored-by-compiler statements are all gone :)

The thing that's surprising here, is that you can't do that with VBA user code. If you made a `MyShape` class with a `DoSomething` method:

```
'@ModuleDescription "A metaphorical Shape"
Option Explicit

Public Sub DoSomething()
    MsgBox TypeName(Me)
End Sub
```

And then a `MyRectangle` class that implements `MyShape` and exposes a member on its own public interface, that yields a `MyShape` object reference:

```
'@ModuleDescription "A metaphorical Rectangle"
Option Explicit
Private sh As MyShape
Implements MyShape

Public Property Get Thing() As Object
    Set Thing = sh
End Property

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set sh = New MyShape
End Sub

Private Sub MyShape_DoSomething()
    MsgBox TypeName(Me)
End Sub
```

And now in any standard module, we can test this - first, all early-bound, and we'll have a factory method that returns a `MyShape`, to mimick `Shapes.CreateShape`:

```
Public Sub WorksMaybe()
    Dim r As MyShape
    Set r = CreateRect
    r.Thing.DoSomething
End Sub

Private Function CreateRect() As MyShape
    Set CreateRect = New MyRectangle
End Function
```

So we run this (on Windows), and I expected, the code doesn't compile:

[image: Compile error: method of data member not found]

Late binding however...

```
Public Sub WorksMaybe()
    Dim r As Object
    Set r = CreateRect
    r.Thing.DoSomething
End Sub

Private Function CreateRect() As MyShape
    Set CreateRect = New MyRectangle
End Function
```

...works? Nope:

[image: run-time error 438: "object doesn't support this property or method"]

Are we not looking at a `MyRectangle` object? No: we're looking at the limits of *late-binding polymorphism* in VBA - we created a `New MyRectangle`, but to the compiler `CreateRect` returns a `MyShape` object reference. If we place a breakpoint on `End Function`, run it, and then type `?TypeName(CreateRect)` in the immediate pane (Ctrl+G) when the breakpoint is hit, then despite the *declared type* being `MyShape`, the *runtime type* is clearly `MyRectangle`.

*And it **should** work* - but it doesn't. Error 438, member not found: the late-bound/run-time equivalent of the "method or data member not found" compile error.

And if we use the interface we really mean to work with...

```
Public Sub WorksMaybe()
    Dim r As MyRectangle
    Set r = CreateRect
    r.Thing.DoSomething
End Sub

Private Function CreateRect() As MyShape
    Set CreateRect = New MyRectangle
End Function
```

...then everything "just works":

[image: "MyShape" message box in front of a giant blue shape on a worksheet]

Now, I'm not running this on a Mac, but this code compiles for me...

```
Option Explicit
Const DistanceBetweenCells As Long = 50
Const LineWidth As Long = 2

Public Sub WorksMaybe()
    Dim r As Excel.Rectangle
    Set r = CreateRect
    r.ShapeRange.Fill.BackColor.RGB = vbRed
End Sub

Private Function CreateRect() As Excel.Shape
    Set CreateRect = Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 40, 40, DistanceBetweenCells, LineWidth)
End Function
```

...and systematically raises run-time error 13 as soon as `CreateRect` returns and the `Shape` reference gets assigned to a `Rectangle` - error 13 being "type mismatch". In other words, a `Rectangle` is *not* a `Shape` (!!?!??). Proof, if we make `CreateRect` return a `Excel.Rectangle`, we now get the type mismatch error as soon as we try to assign the function's return value, and nothing makes sense anymore: there's something weird going on, and, well, I'm out of ideas - there doesn't appear to be any way to work early-bound with a `Rectangle`, despite what `TypeName(Selection)` claims the type is (the class is hidden/undocumented for a reason after all!), which... pretty much destroys all hope, especially if neither `With Selection.Fill` nor `With MyShape.Fill` work (it does work perfectly fine here on my Windows box though).

Sending a frown with some repro code through the user feedback feature should get you heard from the product team at Microsoft. I doubt they removed anything from anywhere - but it's not impossible something broke how interfaces are resolved, somewhere deep down in some seemingly unrelated piece of internal API :)

Comment: Thanks for the input, but I already tried that.  Instead of selecting, I've tried both of the following:  "With MyShape.ShapeRange.Fill" and "With MyShape.Shape.Fill."  I get the same compile error with both.  And of course the crazy part is that the code works with the prior version 16.28.

Comment: I tried just what you suggested and got the same error message.  I do see that "fill" is also not listed as a possible member.  I'm not that familiar with the list of members in the first place, but "fill" is not one of them.

Comment: BTW I just tried your suggestion on Windows and it works fine, just as my original code did.  It's something about Excel version 16.29 and 16.30 on Mac.  I may just have to wait for Microsoft to fix something, but they may never do so!  But thanks for your suggestions and helping think this through.

Comment: An a-hah moment - Based on your suggestion of MyShape.fill, I reported that "Fill" is not on the list of members on V 16.29.  But it is on the list with version 16.28.  So that's the issue, I believe.  Microsoft has removed certain member properties (I'm not sure if properties is the right word) from version 16.29.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think it is figured out.  In Mac Excel version 16.29 Microsoft has deleted certain class members for, at least, Shapes.  For instance "Fill" and "Select" are no longer available.  So any code that refers to them will generate an error.
I'm not sure how extensive this is or any other ramifications, but I do know that the code works fine in version 16.28, and also that the member list in 16.28 shows both "fill" and "select" but not in 16.29.  Thanks to Mathieu Guindon above for the input and also to a poster who deleted his thread - both of these people really helped.  I've reported the issue to Microsoft.

Comment: I tried to get to the bottom of this (see my edited & undeleted answer), and failed, and on the way (and in front of an actual VBE/debugger with real code to experiment with) came to realize how badly off the mark that answer was... the `Shapes` API behaves strangely on Windows too, and that predates 16.29!

Comment: Thank you so much for trying!  I'm carefully reading your response now.  You've helped me improve my code but I still have my original problem - works fine in Windows and in Mac 16.28 but does not work in 16.29.  I cannot think of a way to get it to work, so I'm stuck.

Comment: I know "send a frown" feels like talking to a wall or shouting into the void, but I can assure you that the Excel team gets them and reviews them all. I have a number of contacts, I'll reach out and see if they know anything about this, and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

Answer from [Steve Rindsberg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1667023/steve-rindsberg) [(MVP)](https://mvp.microsoft.com/en-us/PublicProfile/7296?fullName=Steve%20Rindsberg):

> Iterate through the `.ShapeRange` collection:
>
> ```
> For x = 1 To .ShapeRange.Count
>    With .ShapeRange(x)
>        '...stuff....
>    End With
> Next
> ```
>
> I've had a few similar weird ones on Mac where perfectly good code (on
>   Windows) errors or sometimes make the Mac app go POOF! And disappear.
>   Iterating the collections this way has been the fix.